# Will the vent arrangement for my bathtub pass inspection?

Tags: bathtub, vent, bathroom-fixtures, slab, wet

4 fixture bathroom - Florida inspector says all fixtures need to be wet vented in bathroom.

I want to ask if the bathtub to the right with its own vent will work. I believe the inspector is wanting the bathtub on right to also be on a wet vent. If I make the vanity a 3" drain pipe instead of the current 2" and then redirect the 2" bathtub drain pipe to the shared 3" vent of the sink would that be allowed?

[image]

Comment: we can't see what you see.  Pleas add pics.

Comment: Doesn't really matter what we think or what you think. If the inspector insists on it, you're most likely going to have to do it.